# rsync permissions errors at destination even though root, possibly due to sticky bit?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, rsync

I'm using `rsync` to backup local files to a usb disk. That has been working fine for years, but now `rsync` is reporting filesystem permission errors, even though **run as root on a rw filesystem**. This is the command that I run and part of the log outputs:

```
$ sudo rsync --verbose --archive --delete --partial --inplace /var/ /mnt/backup/var
[...]
log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.1
log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.10.gz
log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.2.gz
log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.3.gz
log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.4.gz
log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.5.gz
log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.6.gz
log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.7.gz
log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.8.gz
log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.9.gz
spool/anacron/cron.daily
tmp/
tmp/systemd-private-3bbae922a969453097f3c87f9cfcc52d-fwupd.service-iiu3gi/
tmp/systemd-private-3bbae922a969453097f3c87f9cfcc52d-fwupd.service-iiu3gi/tmp/
rsync: open "/mnt/backup/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/mnt/backup/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.1" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/mnt/backup/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.10.gz" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/mnt/backup/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.2.gz" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/mnt/backup/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.3.gz" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/mnt/backup/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.4.gz" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/mnt/backup/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.5.gz" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/mnt/backup/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.6.gz" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/mnt/backup/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.7.gz" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/mnt/backup/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.8.gz" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: open "/mnt/backup/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.9.gz" failed: Permission denied (13)

sent 568,313,680 bytes  received 11,776 bytes  32,475,740.34 bytes/sec
total size is 9,562,808,631  speedup is 16.83
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]
```

As said, I'm running this as root and the destination filesystem is mounted rw. See these `mount` outputs:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mapper/backup-backup on /mnt/backup type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user)
```

Notice that `rsync` only complains about file permissions in the **destination** directory. Also, I only observe these errors, if some of the files have been **changed** in the source directory. If the files are missing in the destination directory, `rsync` copies them just fine. If the files have not changed since previous run, `rsync` detects that successfully and omits them from copying. It does not emit errors or warnings in either of these situations.

I'm not experiencing much trouble with other files that the above `rsync` command processes. Everything looks just fine for these.

One thing that I notice though, is that the parent directory of the failing files has its sticky flag set:

```
$ sudo ls -la /mnt/backup/var/log/postgresql/
total 48
drwxrwxr-t  2 root     postgres 4096 Mar  6 00:00 .
drwxrwxr-x 17 root     syslog   4096 Mar  6 00:00 ..
-rw-r-----  1 postgres adm         0 Mar  6 00:00 postgresql-12-main.log
-rw-r-----  1 postgres adm      1873 Mar  6 00:00 postgresql-12-main.log.1
-rw-r-----  1 postgres adm       437 Dec 12 09:37 postgresql-12-main.log.10.gz
-rw-r-----  1 postgres adm       701 Feb 27 00:00 postgresql-12-main.log.2.gz
-rw-r-----  1 postgres adm       436 Feb 20 00:00 postgresql-12-main.log.3.gz
-rw-r-----  1 postgres adm       435 Feb 13 00:00 postgresql-12-main.log.4.gz
-rw-r-----  1 postgres adm       535 Feb  6 00:00 postgresql-12-main.log.5.gz
-rw-r-----  1 postgres adm       720 Jan 30 00:00 postgresql-12-main.log.6.gz
-rw-r-----  1 postgres adm       453 Jan 23 00:00 postgresql-12-main.log.7.gz
-rw-r-----  1 postgres adm       453 Jan 13 10:49 postgresql-12-main.log.8.gz
-rw-r-----  1 postgres adm       441 Jan  5 22:00 postgresql-12-main.log.9.gz
```

But so do some other directories that I throw at `rsync` and those do not cause any errors. Needless to say that I can use other CLI tools to manipulate the above files without any trouble as long as I do it as root.

I get the feeling that I must be missing something really obvious. Can anyone tell me what is going on here? And maybe propose some rsync flags or mount options that could fix this?

Finally, here is some version info:

```
rsync  version 3.1.3  protocol version 31
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
```

*Update:*
Outputs of `sysctl fs`:

```
$ sudo sysctl fs | grep fs.protect
fs.protected_fifos = 1
fs.protected_hardlinks = 1
fs.protected_regular = 2
fs.protected_symlinks = 1
```

Comment: Fyi, I know that I could probably exclude the failing files from the `rsync` run, or tweak the file privileges. But I'd really like to know what's going on here and learn to avoid similar problems in the future.

Comment: What are the values of `sudo sysctl fs | grep fs.protect`? What user ID and which groups is your rsync running as? (You said root, your `$` shell prompt seems to imply otherwise.)

Comment: sorry, I omited the sudo part for brevity. forgot that this could cause confusion. will add it to the original question. but I do indeed run this as root (user 0, group 0)
I'll also add the `sysctl fs` outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to its usual meaning, the 'sticky' flag causes Linux to apply additional protection as a precaution against many security issues in the past, which were caused by privileged services being careless about the shared `/tmp` directory (such as following symlinks planted by a user and being tricked into overwriting files in /etc).

- If the `fs.protected_regular` sysctl is non-zero, then *only* the file's owner is permitted to open existing files for "create + write" (O_CREAT), unless those files are owned by the same uid as the directory itself.

  If `fs.protected_regular` is set to 2, this also applies to directories that are just g+w, not only o+w.
- (Similarly, if the `fs.protected_symlinks` sysctl is non-zero, then symlinks within a sticky directory can only be followed by the *link's* owner. For example, if user A symlinks /etc/passwd to /tmp/passwd, then only user A may attempt to open the /tmp/passwd symlink; everyone else including root is not allowed.)

Comment: This explains where the problem comes from. I was not aware of this at all.
So this is indeed caused by the sticky bit and not an rsync glitch.
I've been able to reproduce it with other commands. E.g. for a test file with similar permissions in the source directory, only the second of these works:

`sudo bash -c 'echo "More text." >> /var/log/postgresql/test.txt'`

`sudo --user=postgres bash -c 'echo "More text." >> /var/log/postgresql/test.txt'`

Comment: Question remains how to solve this. At a first glance, the problem goes away when I remove the `--inplace` flag from my rsync command. This seems consistent with this answer.

Comment: But I'm using `--inplace` for a reason. It solves some problem that I've had with partially written files.
Is there other rsync flags that would work around this problem, while still using `--inplace`?
I guess I wouldn't want to set `fs.protected_regular=0` either. Is there a way to overide the behavior on a per-filesystem basis? E.g. via mount options?

Comment: Fyi, my rsync command fails when trying to change the destination dir. But the problem is rooted in the source dir. Its files have the same permissions as listed in the question.
I assume that these permissions come from some postgres ubuntu package. But do they even make sense? Shouldn't the dir and the files inside be owned by the same user?

Comment: Most distributions probably have `protected_regular` disabled, it's the symlink/hardlink restrictions that are most important (and have been added first).

Comment: Indeed different distributions seem to handle this differently. I've just retested this on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian, and I didn't run into this problem at all. Turns out that `fs.protected_regular=0` is set there.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that my problem can also be solved by removing the `--inplace` option from my `rsync` command. That will cause `rsync` create a new file and delete the old one.

That will kinda outsmart the sticky bit functionality described in [user1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686/user1686)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1708329/1673548) (see comments there). Without `--inplace`, `rsync` will never actually open the existing file for write, so `fs.protected_regular=2` does not cause any trouble.

Not sure, if that works for all combinations of permissions on directories with the sticky bit and the files therein. But it works for me so far.

That said, I opted for user1886's answer instead, so I'll leave that as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
find /mnt/backup/var type d perm /1000 print0 > sticky_dirs
xargs -0 --arg-file=sticky_dirs chmod -t
your rsync command here
xargs -0 --arg-file=sticky_dirs chmod +t
```

to turn off all the sticky bits, and then restore them.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good idea. Unfortunately it does not work quite as expected, at least not with the rsync args that I'm using.
Problem is that rsync processes the directory itself before it processes the files inside it. And that resets the file permissions in the destination directory to match the ones used in the source directory, including the sticky bit.

Comment: I guess there are 2 options to make this work after all: 1. Do not use the `--archive` argument, or any other rsync argument that copies permissions from source to dest. 2. Run this answer on the source directory rather than on the destination directory. Personally, I'd like to avoid either of these options.